# How to retrieve binary file from aws secrets manager using aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-secrets-manager

After uploading a binary secret using something like

```
aws secretsmanager create-secret --name my-file-secret --secret-binary fileb://mysecret.file
```

I'm having trouble retrieving the file using the CLI.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The secret is stored as a base64 encoded string in the `SecretBinary` field of the secret value.

To retrieve it, you need to : get the secret value, extract the `SecretBinary` from the resulting JSON, base64 decode it and then save in a file

```
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id $SECRET_ID  --query SecretBinary --output text | base64 --decode > myretrievedsecret.file
```

Comment: Thank you, it works.